# APNS "invalid token" error-response (code 8)

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I'm using APNS to send push notifications from my app to ~300 devices. I get an error response from APNS with code 8 (invalid token) for some of the devices. When I send again to all devices, I get the code 8 error response again, but for different devices (for some of the devices I always get this error, and for some I never get it).

I sent a request to the APNS feedback service but it did not return any errors for the app (this service should return "expired" tokens - in case the intended app doesn't exist on the device anymore).

I know that the "invalid token" error is commonly a result of environment mismatch - trying to send notifications from the APNS production server to a token that came from the sandbox environment, or vice versa. I can't see how that can be the case here, because the same token sometimes gets an error and sometimes doesn't.

Does anyone know of a different reason for APNS "invalid token" response?